# Select all body except one element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to select all the body's elements in jQuery except "this", or the one being hovered on. I'm trying to get the body to go to a certain opacity, but "this" to maintain its opacity. This is my code:

```
$(".content img").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: "1",
    });

    $("body").find('*').not($(this)).animate({
        opacity: "0.4",
    });
});  







    <div class="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h4>Handbags</h4>
                    <img src="FullSizeRender (1).jpg" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h4>Beach bags</h4>
                    <img src="FullSizeRender (2).jpg" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h4>Purses</h4>
                    <img src="IMG_5213.JPG" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h4>Bottle carriers</h4>
                    <img src="FullSizeRender (5).jpg" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h4>Baskets</h4>
                    <img src="img1.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h4>Vases</h4>
                    <img src="img2.jpg" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h4>Placemats</h4>
                    <img src="img6.jpg" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h4>Coasters</h4>
                    <img src="IMG_4665.JPG" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="tiss">
                        <h4>Tissue box covers</h4>
                        <img src="img3.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="ornament">
                        <h4>Holiday ornaments</h4>
                        <img src="img4.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: To produce the desired effect you cannot simply exclude `this`, you have to exclude `this` as well as all of its parents up to the `<body>` tag.

Comment: what html you have?

Comment: I'm using HTML 5

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl; above is my HTML and my jQuery.

Comment: Put a common class on items you want to fade.... and use closest() and not() to exclude the current one

Comment: Yes closest() is working, but only it's doing the inverse of my goal, making 'this' faded and the body opaque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, use CSS to handle hover set new height, when not hovered the height will back to whatever you have before.

Also with hover and callback(not hovered), you can set all other to `opacity: "0.4"` on hover, and reset all when mouse move out (`opacity: "1"`)

```js
$(".content").hover(function() {
  $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
  $("body").find("*").not(this).animate({
    opacity: "0.4"
  }, 1000);
}, function() {
  $("body").find("*").stop().animate({
    opacity: "1"
  }, 0);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
}

.heigher {
  height: 100px;
}

.content:hover {
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: height 1s linear;   
  -moz-transition: height 1s linear;   
  -ms-transition: height 1s linear;   
  -o-transition: height 1s linear;   
  transition: height 1s linear; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">content 1</div>
<div class="content">content 2</div>
<div class="content">content 3</div>
<div class="content heigher">content 4</div>
<div class="content">content 5</div>
<div class="content heigher">content 6</div>
```

## UPDATED Version:

```js
$(".content img").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).parent().animate({
    opacity: "1",
  });

  $(".content").find('img').not($(this)).parent().animate({
    opacity: "0.4",
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <h4>Handbags</h4>
      <img src="FullSizeRender (1).jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <h4>Beach bags</h4>
      <img src="FullSizeRender (2).jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <h4>Purses</h4>
      <img src="IMG_5213.JPG" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <h4>Bottle carriers</h4>
      <img src="FullSizeRender (5).jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <h4>Baskets</h4>
      <img src="img1.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <h4>Vases</h4>
      <img src="img2.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <h4>Placemats</h4>
      <img src="img6.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <h4>Coasters</h4>
      <img src="IMG_4665.JPG" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="tiss">
        <h4>Tissue box covers</h4>
        <img src="img3.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="ornament">
        <h4>Holiday ornaments</h4>
        <img src="img4.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried this but it's not working with me either.

Comment: @MullerA which part not working? check the updated code (2nd code snippet)

Answer (score 0):

Bulk-selecting like that probably isn't going to give the result you're after, since it would still target the children and parents of the element you want to keep opaque - lowering its opacity in the process.

There are a few different ways you could handle this. You might add some kind of "mask" element (typically an empty div is used for things like this) with a translucent background-color (ala `rgba(255,255,255,0.5)`). Getting the hovered-on item to override that mask could be done by changing the z-index, so everything that's not hovered is at a lower index than the mask div and the thing getting hovered is at a higher one.

That said, you might want to think twice about this. What's the benefit of making the non-hovered parts of the site harder to see? Could you find another way to highlight the hovered item for emphasis, without fading out everything else? Keep usability in mind when you're dealing with questions like this one.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something where the hovered-upon image expands and covers the foreground leaving the rest of the website in the "background" and of a lower opacity.