# JQuery - Animate() function still performs an animation on the .not(...), .not('...'), :not(...) and the :not('...') elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to state this should be a really simple thing, I really thought there was something about this problem in the forum, however, didn't find anything.

So, from the title, you can already say what's wrong. My code shouldn't hide `#player-one-turn` element. I know, it's in the parent called `#fourth-step` (but every element has it's parent `body`), however, I wouldn't like to change the DOM here. Maybe it's necessary, I don't know.

---

```js
$("#fourth-step").not($('#player-one-turn')).animate({
  opacity: 0
});

// SAME AS ABOVE - DOESN'T WORK
//$("#fourth-step:not('#player-one-turn')").animate({ opacity: 0 });
//$("#fourth-step:not('#player-one-turn')").animate({ opacity: 0 });
//$("#fourth-step:not(#player-one-turn)").animate({ opacity: 0 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fourth-step">
  <div id="player-one-turn">
    DONT HIDE ME PLS
  </div>
  asd asd as das das das d asd as
</div>
```

JsFiddle in case of better editing: https://jsfiddle.net/ax07dnrf/1/.

---

These cases didn't work:

```
$("#fourth-step").not($('#player-one-turn')).animate({ opacity: 0 });
$("#fourth-step:not('#player-one-turn')").animate({ opacity: 0 });
$("#fourth-step:not('#player-one-turn')").animate({ opacity: 0 });
$("#fourth-step:not(#player-one-turn)").animate({ opacity: 0 });
```

Syntax error? I don't think so :D

---

Threads similar to my problem, however, both using `:not()` or `.not()` didn't work in my example:

1. [Select all body except one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609436/select-all-body-except-one-element)
2. [jquery - run function on each element except the one that was clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445952/jquery-run-function-on-each-element-except-the-one-that-was-clicked/4446016)

Comment: An element with a specific ID will always not have a different ID.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - should be? select by id, but not with id?

Comment: I meant that you can just pass a selector to `.not()`, you don't need to pass another jQuery object. But, yes, you're right.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Doesn't work my friend :(

Comment: Have you read the other comments? Your selector amounts to "Find 'Joe' and out of what was found, exclude 'Tim'". Tim will not be excluded when it wasn't part of the initial selection.

Comment: You say your code should not hide `#player-one-turn`, but you're not telling us what it *should* hide. I have no idea what you want to accomplish here.

Comment: *Everything* except `#player-one-turn` element's content.

Comment: You can't. If the opacity of its parent is `0`, all its content will be invisible too.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, however, I'd like to do it, anyway. Maybe we should change the DOM then?

Comment: If by "everything", you actually meant "everything inside `fourth-step`", then that's different. Put the text in an element, and fade that. If you do want the parent faded, then yeah, I think you'll need to rework the structure.

Comment: So then I guess you *don't* mean "everything". Your question started of suggesting that we'd know what you're talking about just by your title, when in fact there are many ways to interpret what you want. You started to give more explanation, but you language remained very broad. Try to be more specific in your descriptions, as it is often the case that there could be multiple valid interpretations that you haven't considered.

Comment: And FYI, if you change the markup as others have shown, you can do it all in the selector, making it more portable: `#fourth-step > :not("#player-one-turn")`.

Comment: ...and I didn't realize people still used jQuery for animations. You can do this in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector says to find the one element that has an `id` of `fourth-step` and from that found element, exclude the element with an `id` of `#player-one-turn`. But, `#player-one-turn` will not be part of what's found by the first selector, so it can't be excluded.

You need to look at all the ***child elements*** within `fourth-step` and exclude `#player-one-turn` from those results.

The plain text `asd asd as das das das d asd as` is not considered a child element within the parent and so it is excluded. But, if you wrap it in an element (like `span`), it will be included.

```js
// You don't have to pass a jQuery object to .not(), just a selector
$("#fourth-step").children().not('#player-one-turn').animate({
  opacity: 0
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fourth-step">
  <div id="player-one-turn">DONT HIDE ME PLS</div>
  <div>HIDE ME PLS</div>
  <div>HIDE ME PLS</div>  
  asd asd as das das das d asd as
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#fourth-step").contents().not($("#player-one-turn")[0]).wrap("<div></div>").parent().animate({
  opacity: 0
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fourth-step">
  <div id="player-one-turn">
    DONT HIDE ME PLS
  </div>
  asd asd as das das das d asd as
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain the use of `children()` here, pls?

Comment: What am I doing wrong? Have no idea, sorry. https://jsfiddle.net/hohg2xrr/.

Comment: This code will have no effect on the DOM provided. The only child element has been excluded by the `.not()`.

Comment: Nice edit, it worked. As I can see, you just wrapped my below `#player-one-turn` text by the `<span></span>`. Without element wrapping by other tags, it it possible to accomplish the same result?

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis - here you go

Answer (score 1):

You can even use **find()** and implement it.
To understand [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```js
$("#fourth-step").find('*').not('#player-one-turn').animate({
  opacity: 0
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fourth-step">
  <div id="player-one-turn">
    DONT HIDE ME PLS
  </div>
  <span>asd asd as das das das d asd as</span>
</div>
```